# More pythonic way to change multilevel dictionary values

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

For example, I have the following dict:

```
{'foo': 'test', 
 'bar': {'test1': 'some text here'},
 'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'some text here', 'test4': 'some text here'}}}
```

Or something like this, maybe more levels.

Now the question is, I want to change...`'some text here'` to `'A test'`. Yeah, I can use a lot of `for` loops like the following code:

```
d = {'foo': 'test',
     'bar': {'test1': 'some text here'},
     'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'some text here',
                       'test4': 'some text here'}}}

for i in d:
    if d[i] == 'some text here':
        d[i] = 'A test'

    elif type(d[i]) == dict:
        for j in d[i]:
            if d[i][j] == 'some text here':
                d[i][j] = 'A test'

            elif type(d[i][j]) == dict:
                for n in d[i][j]:
                    if d[i][j][n] == 'some text here':
                        d[i][j][n] = 'A test'

__import__('pprint').pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'bar': {'test1': 'A test'},                                                    
 'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'A test', 'test4': 'A test'}},
 'foo': 'test'}
```

However I don't think this is a good way...Any ideas?

Comment: @user2393267: That called tags, not labels :)

Comment: What is the criterion for replacement, exact match of any value at any depth?

Comment: @qarma: Well, actually I said that in my question: *Maybe more levels*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as values you are changing are not too hairy, here's a one-liner:

```
In [29]: data = dict(foo=12, bar=dict(dd=12), ex=dict(a=dict(b=dict(v=12))))

In [30]: json.loads(re.sub("12", "33", json.dumps(data)))
Out[30]: {'bar': {'dd': 33}, 'ex': {'a': {'b': {'v': 33}}}, 'foo': 33}
```

EDIT, per Kevin, simple substitution doesn't even need `re`:

```
json.loads(json.dumps(data).replace("12", "33"))
```

Comment: Well...Why I didn't try this...Great! BTW, two hits: 1. this will also replace keys if there's `12` in keys, maybe use `': 33'` instead of `'33'`? 2. Why don't just use `str.replace()`?

Comment: Good point, `.replace()` is even better! As long as values are unique enough. I used `re` specifically for possible special cases, like keys.

Comment: If you are going to brute force it in this manner why even bother with json when str and eval can do what you want `eval(str({'foo': 33}).replace('33', '11'))`.

Comment: @justinfay because `eval` is evil and because `__repr__` representation produces inconsistent quotes `['Jeanne', "d'Arc"]`

Answer (score 3):

This looks like a good case for recursion.

```
import re

def replace_rec(data, search, replace, _pattern=None):
    if _pattern is None:
        _pattern = re.compile(r'^%s$' % search)
    for k, v in data.items():
        try:
            data[k] = _pattern.sub(replace, v)
        except TypeError:
            try:
                replace_rec(data[k], search, replace, _pattern=_pattern)
            except AttributeError:
                # Leave any other types as they are.
                continue
```

Use it for your example like this:

```
>>> data = {
...     'foo': 'test',
...     'bar': {'test1': 'some text here'},
...     'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'some text here', 'test4': 'some text here'}},
...     'loc': [1, 2, 3],
...     'fp': 'foo some text here foo',
... }
>>> replace_rec(data, 'some text here', 'A test')
>>> pprint.pprint(data)
{'bar': {'test1': 'A test'},
 'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'A test', 'test4': 'A test'}},
 'foo': 'test',
 'fp': 'foo some text here foo',
 'loc': [1, 2, 3]}
```

Answer (score 1):

A slightly alternative version. This correctly handles non-strings in your dictionaries, and only replaces an exact text match.

```
def replace(d, find_text, replace_text):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            replace(v, find_text, replace_text)
        elif isinstance(v, str):
            if v == find_text:
                d[k] = replace_text

d = {
    'test': 'dont change some text here',
    'ignore' : 42,

    'foo': 'test', 
    'bar': {'test1': 'some text here'},
    'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'some text here', 'test4': 'some text here'}}}       

replace(d, 'some text here', 'A test')

__import__('pprint').pprint(d)
```

This would display:

```
{'bar': {'test1': 'A test'},
 'baz': {'test2': {'test3': 'A test', 'test4': 'A test'}},
 'foo': 'test',
 'ignore': 42,
 'test': 'dont change some text here'}
```

Comment: Well, I think there is no large difference between your answer and justinfay's earlier, accepted answer. So his answer has a problem about  non-strings, maybe a comment would be better than another answer.

Comment: His answer would also replace "don't change some text here". It wasn't clear from your question if this case also needed to be replaced.

Comment: Hmm...understand, so his answer can solve my question, that's enough. And your question is more useful if my dict was more complex. right? I've upvoted your answer.

Comment: You probably should have just edited my answer to include checking if it was a string as the structure of your function is exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

Recursive answers are all fun and games, yet you could get more Pythonic by noting that dictionaries are mutable:

First get references to all dictionaries (at all levels), then change them.

```
def all_dicts(d):
    yield d
    for v in d.values():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            yield from all_dicts(v)

data = dict(foo=12, bar=dict(dd=12), ex=dict(a=dict(b=dict(v=12))))

for d in all_dicts(data):
     for k, v in d.items():
         if v == 12:
             d[k] = 33
```